# Probablity that both events occur when atleast one does

Tags: self-study

I have a problem where P(A), P(B) and P(A and B) are given. The question is asking what the probability of both happening if one does. These events in dependent since P(A and B) != P(A)P(B)

I thought that I could use the formula: P(A and B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A or B)
and setting P(A or B) to 1, but that doesn't seem to work.

Probably has something to do with conditional probability, but the question doesn't specify if it is A or B that happens first so I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks

Edit:

What is P(A and B) given that A or B happens

Comment: Can you paste in the actual question?

Comment: I should probably avoid pasting in the actual question. To be more specific, I need to find the probability that both A and B happen given that A or B happens

Comment: That's a straight conditional probability problem. "Which happens first" is irrelevant; they may not even be ordered in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confused the probability of a union with that of an intersection:

$$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

The definition of conditional probability is:

$$P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Please don't give complete solutions to obvious homework-style questions. Please follow the guidelines at the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: @Glen_b in the interests of keeping with community norms, I've removed my answer...just left the hint.

Comment: Okay thanks.... I think there's an intermediate position between what you started with and what you have now that would still be okay. For example describing how to deal with the numerator (which you had explicitly in your previous answer) might be exactly the hint that gets them over the hurdle.

Comment: @Glen_b no worries...sometimes I get a little overzealous with my answers. I've given a little less than what the numerator should be, but I will provide additional info via comments if there is still trouble.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't think of using P((A and B) | (A or B)), pretty obvious now that I know..... I admit to seeing your original post, and I'm not sure why (A or B) was eliminated from the conjunction in the numerator. Is that because (A or B) is guaranteed to happen? So its a set in union with the complete set. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Avernikas think of a Venn diagram for the conjunction : (A and B) and (A or B)...

Comment: Right, it would just always be like that regardless. That's enough to go on, thanks a lot!